# Clash between \footnote{} and \widetilde{} in revtex document class

Tags: footnotes, revtex, tilde

I am writing a research paper using the revtek4-2 (or revtex4-1) document class, and I need to write a footnote containing a mathematical symbol that requires \widetilde (*not* \tilde). It seems that the \footnote{} environment clashes with \widetilde{}, as can be seen from the following minimal working example. Any idea on how to circumvent this issue?

Thank you!

Note 1: if I replace \widetilde{} with \tilde{} everything works, but \tilde{} is not ideal in my case, I really need to use \widetilde{} instead.

Note 2: this issue does not occur for other document classes such as "article", but for publication reasons I have to stick with the revtex4-2 (or revtex4-1) document class.

Note 3: I am using Overleaf to compile the .tex source.

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,reprint]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

Here is an example of a footnote with ``widetilde" \footnote{Let us try: $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}_{ij}}$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever there is a "fragile command in moving argument" error you can apply `\protect` to prevent premature expansion. Unrelated but  `''` not `"`.

You will need to remove the broken `.bbl` file from earlier attempt then run pdflaex, bibtaex, pdflatex, pdflatex.

[image]

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,reprint]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

Here is an example of a footnote with 
``widetilde''\footnote{Let us try: $\protect\widetilde{\mathcal{M}_{ij}}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is obviously `amsfonts` not making `\widetilde` robust.

Comment: @egreg yes but this is an answer for a document author, not the ams

Answer (score 2):

The commands `\widetilde` and `\widehat` are redefined by `amsfonts` in order to use also wider variants, but the package fails to make them robust like the kernel commands.

If you have a few of such cases, add `\protect` in front of `\widetilde` or `\widehat` when in moving arguments.

For a more practical solution, make the command robust. It requires removing the kernel definitions, though.

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,reprint]{revtex4-2}

%% remove the kernel inner definition of \widetilde and \widehat
\ExpandArgs{c}\let{widetilde }\relax
\ExpandArgs{c}\let{widehat }\relax
% make them robust
\MakeRobust\widetilde
\MakeRobust\widehat

\begin{document}

Here is an example of a footnote with
``widetilde''\footnote{Let us try: $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}_{ij}}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have an older LaTeX version which complains about `\ExpandArgs`, you can replace the two lines using it with

```
\expandafter\let\csname widetilde \endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname widehat \endcsname\relax
```

The spaces are important.